# JavaScript access elements from custom object

Tags: javascript, oop

This must be a very stupid question, but I just can't get it to work.

I'm creating my own UIKit for iOS. (Website-kit which will allow iPhone-like interfaces).

But, I'm trying to create a JavaScript library, which can be used to change several elements of the document. For instance, set a custom background colour when the document loads.

I'm trying to do that with object-orientated JavaScript. Like this:

```
var UI = new Interface();
UI.setBackground("#000");
```

How could I achieve this?
(So the custom "UI" Object, and (an example) on how to change the background color of the document, from INSIDE the object.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save a reference to the DOM inside the JS object and rewrite it as needed.

```
function Interface() {
    this.setBackground = function (color) {
        this.pointTo.style.background = color;
    };
    this.pointTo = document.body;
}
```

You can initialize this by:

```
var UI = new Interface();
UI.pointTo = document.getElementById('some_id');
UI.setBackground("#000");
// Set another style, on a different element
UI.pointTo = document.getElementById('some_other_id');
UI.setBackground("#FFF");
```

This is a simple implementation and need to be allot smarter, but it should do the job.

Edit:
Made a mistake in original posting, and fixed erroneous code. Also made an example: http://jsfiddle.net/HpW3E/

Answer (score 1):

Like silverstrike's code, but you can pass the target object in the interface constructor to don't get trouble in the future.

```
function Interface(target) {
    target = target || document.body;
    this.setBackground = function (color) {
        target.style.background = color || 'white';
    };
}
```

Ok now you can do this:

```
var UI = new Interface(document.body);
UI.setBackground("#000");
```

or even in somecases that you are applying the interface in `global scope` !ONLY!:

```
var UI = new Interface(this.body);
UI.setBackground("#000");
```

Also will work as this:

```
var UI = new Interface();
UI.setBackground("#000");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple approach

```
// define the object
var Interface = function () {

    var interface = document.getElementById("interface"); // just an example

    // your new methods
    this.setBackground = function (color) {
        interface.style.backgroundColor = color;
    }

    // rest of your code
}
```

now you can make use of it

```
var UI = new Interface();
UI.setBackground("#000");
```

Comment: I already tried something similair to that, but the problem is that the "document" object won't work inside a method...